# Class Instance or Inherited Class for a game? Best Practice

Tags: c#, performance, class, inheritance

So I'm building a small game framework to reinforce abstract classes and interfaces. I've been building classes for some mechanics and I'm not sure how to deal with the final pieces.

Here's the class framework (with some miscellaneous methods removed):

```
public abstract class Ability
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual string Stat { get; set; }
    public virtual float Scale { get; set; }
    public virtual float MPCost { get; set; }
    public virtual float SPCost { get; set; }
}

public class Attack : Ability
{
    public float BaseDmg { get; set; }
    public bool isUnblockable { get; set; }

    public float GetDmg(int stat)
    {
        return BaseDmg * (1 + stat * Scale);
    }
}
```

Now for the actual Attacks I want to create, should I instantiate like I have been?

```
public static class AllAttacks
{
    //Physical Attacks
    public static Attack slash = new Attack();

    //Magical Attacks
    public static Attack push = new Attack();

    public static void Generate()
    {
        //Physical Attacks
        slash.Name = "Slash";
        slash.Description = "A simple but effective strike.";
        slash.Type = "physical";
        slash.Stat = "str";
        slash.Scale = 0.1F;
        slash.MPCost = 0;
        slash.SPCost = 1;
        slash.BaseDmg = 5;
        slash.isUnblockable = false;

        //Magical Attacks
        push.Name = "Push";
        push.Description = "A powerful telekinetic strike.";
        push.Type = "magic";
        push.Stat = "int";
        push.Scale = 0.1F;
        push.MPCost = 1;
        push.SPCost = 0;
        push.BaseDmg = 5F;
        push.isUnblockable = false;
    }
```

Or should I actually create a new inherited class for each unique item and then instantiate them in the Fight class? And if I do, should these be static or non-static?

`public class Slash : Attack
    {
         //Code Here
    }`

Could anyone point me to best practices or what the most efficient method would be?

Comment: You might want to read Eric Lippert's [Wizards and Warriors series](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/). If you don't want to read them all, skip ahead to part 5 which contains the real take away.

Comment: This makes your question far too broad. There is no general rule that fits them all.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Really? I have a class that handles fights by getting attacks passed into them. Should I have attacks as class instances like I have now, or should I create new classes for each kind of attack I want to have. What exactly is too broad? I'll rephrase my question if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically there are two main reasons to define a new class: new behavior and/or new contract, that is changed implementation for the former reason or added new public members for the latter. Now considering your example I don't see changed contracts or behaviors for various types of attack (only changed state) so I don't see a reason to define new classes for them. From the readability standpoint the `Generate` method isn't optimal however - I'd create separate methods for different types of attack which would clearly denote what type of attack they create.

As for the instantiation aspects, if you aren't going to mutate your attack instances than get them created in the single place is pretty okay, otherwise you need to control the life cycle of every attack instance on the level where the instance is used.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of advice and guidance I was looking for.

Comment: @Arcaster, Just as a side note, try to avoid separation of instantiation and initialization because of danger to get half-initialized instance and some usage inconveniences. My suggestion is to use static factory methods which would return initialized instances with all properties set up.